# What is according to the RCC the creation story in Genesis?

Tags: catholicism, genesis

Is the creation of Adam and eve a real event in history or is this just a story which actually never really happened and can it according to RCC also be seen as a methaphore? Or is it 'just' a spiritual reality? If so, does this induce problems with the reality of our Earth and other creations?

Answer (score 2):

The Catholic Church teaches, in the decisions of the [1909 Pontifical Biblical Commission](http://sententiaedeo.blogspot.com/2011/08/six-24-hour-days.html?m=1) ([Latin original](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/pcb_documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19090630_genesi_lt.html)), that

> The **first three Chapters of Genesis** contain narratives that **correspond to** objectively real and ***historically* true events** [*rerum vere gestarum narrationes quae scilicet obiectivae realitati et historicae veritati respondeant*], **no myths, no mere allegories or symbols of religious truths, no legends**.

Answer (score -1):

1. To appreciate the reality of Adam & Eve creation as fact and historical one must embrace the reality of God exisitence. in Catholic Church faith it is written as the first article of faith.

   > ARTICLE I
   >   "I BELIEVE IN GOD THE FATHER ALMIGHTY, CREATOR OF HEAVEN AND EARTH"
   >   Paragraph 4. The Creator
   >   279 "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth."116 Holy Scripture begins with these solemn words. The profession of faith takes them up when it confesses that God the Father almighty is "Creator of heaven and earth" (Apostles' Creed), "of all that is, seen and unseen" (Nicene Creed). We shall speak first of the Creator, then of creation and finally of the fall into sin from which Jesus Christ, the Son of God, came to raise us up again.
2. The physical realities of creation is embedded in the first three word in Genesis 1:1 "In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth"... for scientific physical realities it connotes "time, space & matter"...
3. all the scientists including all the famous & the brightest cannot fathom the mystery of our vast universe...But for RCC the universe is not the summit of God Creation...CCC343

   > CCC343 Man is the summit of the Creator's work, as the inspired account expresses by clearly distinguishing the creation of man from that of the other creatures."
4. The historical fact written in the bible Creation of Man is in the sixth day..whether you called 6 B.C or other acceptable timeline the biblical proof is written in the RCC  in CCC342..

   > CCC342 The hierarchy of creatures is expressed by the order of the "six days", from the less perfect to the more perfect. God loves all his creatures209 and takes care of each one, even the sparrow. Nevertheless, Jesus said: "You are of more value than many sparrows", or again: "Of how much more value is a man than a sheep!"
5. So for your other questions"If so, does this induce problems with the reality of our Earth and other creations? The answer is in CCC340

   > CCC340 God wills the interdependence of creatures. The sun and the moon, the cedar and the little flower, the eagle and the sparrow: the spectacle of their countless diversities and inequalities tells us that no creature is self-sufficient. Creatures exist only in dependence on each other, to complete each other, in the service of each other."

   But the most striking historical,biblical & spiritual truth in all of this is who is the Center of Creation,I mean why all this things existed in the first place?

   > For in Him/Jesus all things were created, things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities. All things were created through Him and for Him. (Colossians 1:16)

Comment: Why would you rollback my edit which did nothing except make it readable and fix a typo?

Comment: curiousdanni sorry i thought rollback means your edited version will be posted..im not yet familiar with all the functions of guide button..my apology.Godbless