# (Catholic view) What was the scriptural basis for the existence of limbo?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, limbo

Looking at [this other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/in-catholic-doctrine-is-limbo-eternal), limbo is an intermediary place for (some) souls to dwell in until they get to heaven.

One of the answers to the question mentions two kinds of limbo:

- Limbo of hell or of the Patriarchs (limbus inferni seu patrum)
- Limbo for children (limbus puerorum)

What is (or was) the biblical basis for the existence of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the question "[Whether the limbo of hell is the same as Abraham's bosom?](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP069.html#XPQ69A4THEP1)," St. Thomas Aquinas quotes a few scriptural verses:

> The place whither the beggar Lazarus was taken is called [Abraham's bosom](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/46653/1787) [[Luke 16:22](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=16&l=22-#x)-23]. Now he was taken to hell, for as a gloss [*St. Gregory, Moral. xx] on [Job 30:23](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=20&ch=30&l=23-#x), "Where a house is appointed for every one that liveth," says: "Hell was the house of all the living until the coming of Christ." Therefore Abraham's bosom is the same as limbo.