# Limbo part of purgatory?

Tags: catholicism, purgatory, children, limbo

Did any theologians think that the [limbo for children (*limbus puerorum*)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/46653/1787) is part of purgatory?

Comment: If I may, a thought to consider: At the end (the Last Day) there will be no Purgatory; all souls will ultimately be either in Heaven or  in Hell.  I once asked a priest about Limbo, and he said that Limbo was the first level of Hell where souls will have all they desire except God. However, the priest, in my estimation, did not  provide a satisfactory explanation.  The Church, of course, has not defined where the souls, say, of unbaptized aborted children go. Regarding such, I often consider a thought of St. Francis de Sales on a different matter: "... would you assign them hell?"